# Finding orders of elements

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is what are the "possible" orders of Z*20, and the answer is 1, 2, 4 and 8. I understand that the actual orders of Z*20 are 1, 2 and 4 but I don't understand how the "possible" orders are determined.

Secondly, the order of 11 in Z26 is 12. How is this determined?

I can see from another question that 9's order is 2 in Z18 as 9x2 = 0 mod 18. However 11x12 != 0 mod 26 so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Z_{20}^*$, the multiplicative group of the ring $\mathbb Z_{20}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{n}$ are those numbers which are *coprime* to $n$.  In the case of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{20}$ that would be $\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$.  In general, counting how many elements there are coprime to a number can be tedious.  We use [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

Next, by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29), the order of an element must divide the order of the group (*in the case of a finite group*).  Since $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{20}$ has exactly $8$ elements, and the only divisors of $8$ are $1,2,4,8$, the result follows.

---

As for $11$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_{26},+)$, you are correct that $11$ is not of order $12$ (seen easily since $11\cdot 12\equiv 2\pmod{26}$)

**However**, $11^{12}\equiv 1\pmod {26}$, so it was likely intended that the group in question would be $(\mathbb{Z}^\times_{26},\times)$.

Comment: But there are no elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb Z_{20}^*$, which was one of the points of the question.

Comment: Thank you. If a question doesn't specify if Zn is multiplicative or additive, is there one that you're supposed to assume over the other?

Comment: @Thomas indeed, but the phrase "possible orders" I interpret as "order $o_1$ *or* $o_2$ *or*...*or* $o_k$," and I would expect that as a first step in figuring out what the exact list of orders present are, that we would first limit our search to those orders which could be present knowing nothing else about the group but the size.

Comment: @foxes If it is written with a times symbol above, generally it would be multiplicative.  Otherwise, if no mention of group operation is given and there is no symbol above the $\mathbb{Z}$, then it is usually additive in my experience, though if you want to make sure your reader knows which you mean, it never hurts to use a few extra words.  I expect that it was intended to be written as $\mathbb{Z}_{26}^\times$ and either the symbol was missed in the writing or reading stages.